# caption vertical spacing broken

Tags: captions, floatrow

I'm trying to migrate my project from `float` package to `floatrow` one (we can't load former with the latter as it is said in documentation for `floatrow`).

I extensively used `ruled` style. Most obvious thing after switch to `floatrow` is broken vertical alignment when caption goes to multiple lines.

[image]

Spacing between the caption text and the rules is quite different for some reason. Looks awful.

Second problem is that I can't get working `labelsep=period` from `caption` package.

My MWE is as follows.

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{floatrow}%
\DeclareNewFloatType{LstEnv}{%
placement=htbp,fileext=lol}
\floatsetup[LstEnv]{style=ruled}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[LstEnv]{labelsep=period}

\begin{document}
\begin{LstEnv}[H]
Abc
\caption{My cap}
\end{LstEnv}

\begin{LstEnv}[H]
Abc
\caption{Very long caption Very long caption 
Very long caption Very long caption Very long caption }
\end{LstEnv}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you insert a caption like `\caption{\vrule height30pt}`, you will find that captions have a minimal height. So the **broken** part is when there is only line to show which is too short to prop up the space.

Comment: @Symbol1 not really see how this helps. Are you saying that the package has fundamental flaw?

Comment: I would rather call it *design*. A box having minimal height is not something you can achieve accidentally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution for your issues:

1. Redefine the definition of the above rule

   ```
   \DeclareFloatVCode{thickrule}{\par\rule{\hsize}{.8pt}\strut\par\unskip}
   ```
2. Load `caption` before `floatrow`

The complete code

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{caption,xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{floatrow}%
\DeclareNewFloatType{LstEnv}{%
placement=htbp,fileext=lol}
\DeclareFloatVCode{thickrule}{\par\rule{\hsize}{.8pt}\strut\par\unskip}
\floatsetup[LstEnv]{style=ruled}


\captionsetup[LstEnv]{labelsep=period}

\begin{document}
\begin{LstEnv}
Abc
\caption{My cap}
\end{LstEnv}

\begin{LstEnv}
Abc
\caption{Very long caption Very long caption 
Very long caption Very long caption Very long caption }
\end{LstEnv}
\end{document}
```

and finally the result

[image]